# Export Unity3d prefab as asset bundle with .unity3d extension

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependencies, editor, bundle, assets

I am trying to export a prefab containing other child prefabs as an "asset bundle" with the extension .unity3d.
This is the code I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;


#if UNITY_EDITOR 


public class AssetBundleBuilder : EditorWindow
{
 
    [MenuItem( "Assets/Asset Bundle Builder" )]
    

    static void BuildAssetBundle( )
    {

        GameObject selectedObject = Selection.activeGameObject;
        string bundleName = selectedObject.name;
        List<string> assetPaths = new List<string>( );

        // Bring up save panel
        string path = EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel( "Saving path" , "" , "" );

        if ( selectedObject == null )
        {
            Debug.LogError( "Please select an object to build asset bundle." );
            return;
        }

        string[ ] dependencies = AssetDatabase.GetDependencies( new string[ ] { AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath( selectedObject ) } );

        // Create a list to store the unique paths of the required assets
        // Remove any unnecessary files from the list of dependencies and add unique asset paths to the list


        for ( int i = 0 ; i < dependencies.Length ; i++ )
        {
            if ( dependencies[i].EndsWith( ".cs" ) || dependencies[i].EndsWith( ".js" ) || dependencies[i].EndsWith( ".boo" ) )
            {
                dependencies[i] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                string assetPath = dependencies[i];
                if ( !assetPaths.Contains( assetPath ) )
                {
                    assetPaths.Add( assetPath );
                }
            }
        }

        string outputPath = $"Assets/AssetBundles/{bundleName}";

        bool folderExists = Directory.Exists( outputPath );
        if ( !folderExists )
            Directory.CreateDirectory( outputPath );



        // Set asset bundle build options
        AssetBundleBuild[ ] buildMap = new AssetBundleBuild[1];
        buildMap[0].assetBundleName = $"{bundleName}.unity3d";
        buildMap[0].assetNames = assetPaths.ToArray();


        // Set the asset bundle build options

        BuildAssetBundleOptions buildOptions = BuildAssetBundleOptions.DeterministicAssetBundle
                                             | BuildAssetBundleOptions.UncompressedAssetBundle;
     
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles( outputPath ,  buildMap  , buildOptions , EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget );
       
        // Refresh asset database
        AssetDatabase.Refresh( );

        Debug.Log( $"{bundleName} asset bundle has been successfully built at {outputPath}" );
    }
```

I expect a .unity3d file that can be loaded and which contains all th required dependencies.
The problem is that an error message is triggred when I try to load the resulting file.

Comment: What error are you getting and how are you loading it later?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing this in code instead of using the option built in to the editor for this very purpose?

Comment: Yeah, having the error message would be helpful... And like @LouisIngenthron said, using the Asset Bundle Browser makes life a lot easier! Here is a tut on it: https://youtu.be/QfOqJ-7YAPM?t=165